# OO Javascript - proper scope handling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I've written a short and incomplete example (for the sake of this question) that attempts to use jquery to sum the width of a group of images.  I'm having some issues figuring out how to handle scope in complex OO javascript applications.

```
function imageContainer(){
      this.selector = "img.inContainer";

      this.width = function(){
        var tmp = 0;
        $(this.selector).each(function(){
          // use load to preload images
          $(this).load(function(){ 
             // our 'this' pointer to the original object is long gone,
             // so is it even possible to accumulate a sum without using
             // globals? Ideally, I'd like to increment a temporary value
             // that exists within the scope of this.width();
             tmp+=$(this).width();
          });
        });
        // I'm thinking that returning here is problematic, because our
        // call to each() may not be complete?
        return tmp;
      }

      this.construct = function(){
        alert(this.width());
      }

      this.construct();
}
```

I'm not really looking for a hack around this issue, I'd like to know how this sort of thing **should** be done - in a way that doesn't trash encapsulation.  Am I missing something obvious?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function imageContainer() {
    this.selector = "img.inContainer";

    this.width = function(cb) {
        var tmp = 0;
        var len = this.length;
        var count = 0;
        $(this.selector).each(function() {
            // use load to preload images
            var that = this;
            // load is ajax so it is async
            $(this).load(function() {
                tmp += $(that).width();
                if (++count === len) {
                    // counted all.
                    cb(tmp);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    this.construct = function(cb) {
        this.width(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    };

    this.construct();
}
```

Welcome to ajax. Your doing a bunch of operations in parallel asynchronously. So you need to keep track of how many complete and fire a callback when all have completed.

Any asynchronous operation like `.load` requires you to either *block* for 100s of ms or change your API to use callbacks.

Rather then the `var that = this` pattern you can also use `$.proxy` instead.

```
// load is ajax so it is async
$(this).load($.proxy(function() {
    tmp += $(this).width();
    if (++count === len) {
        // counted all.
        cb(tmp);
    }
}, this));
```

Since you have the construct of doing n ajax tasks before firing your callback you can generalize this with some sugar.

```
this.width = function(cb) {
    // map all images to deferred objects, when deferred objects are resolved
    $.when($.makeArray($(this.selector).map(function() {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        $(this).load(function() {
            def.resolve();
        });
        return def;
    // then sum the widths and fire the callback.
    }))).then($.proxy(function(data) {
        var tmp = 0;
        $(this.selector).each(function() {
             tmp+=$(this).width();
        });
        cb(tmp);
    }, this));
};
```

Notice here I really want to use `$.fn.reduce` but it does not exist. It could have been

```
// reduce the set of images to the sum of their widths.
cb($(this.selector).reduce(0, function(memo, key, val) {
    return memo + $(this).width();
}));
```

On second thought this *sugar* does not make it any simpler, at least it looks more like LISP then C now.